# Chromecast: using IS_CONNECTED_CHANGED to detect receiver connection

Tags: chromecast

I'm trying to add Chromecast capability to an existing app, using Google's [CastVideos-chrome](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-chrome) sample app as a guide. My question is about how the sender detects that it connected to a receiver.

### What I expect/want to happen

The sample app includes the following, which I have basically copied in my implementation (CastVideos.js, lines 165-198):

```js
CastPlayer.prototype.initializeCastPlayer = function() {
  // ...
  this.remotePlayerController.addEventListener(
    cast.framework.RemotePlayerEventType.IS_CONNECTED_CHANGED,
    function(e) {
      this.switchPlayer(e.value);
    }.bind(this)
  );
};
```

Within the CastVideos-chrome app, `setupRemotePlayer()` is only called in `switchPlayer()`, and `switchPlayer()` is only called from the `IS_CONNECTED_CHANGED` listener in the snippet above. So, I ought to be seeing an `IS_CONNECTED_CHANGED` event whenever my app connects to a receiver, in order to set up the remote player.

### My code

When initializing the sender, I add a listener for the `IS_CONNECTED_CHANGED` event. Below is my code (in kotlin-js) and a translation into javascript.

```js
remotePlayerController = js("new cast.framework.RemotePlayerController(new cast.framework.RemotePlayer())")
remotePlayerController.addEventListener(Util.RemotePlayerEventType.IS_CONNECTED_CHANGED) {
    js("function() {" +
         "console.log(\"Remote Player event: IS_CONNECTED_CHANGED\");" +
         "return switchPlayers();" +
    "}")
}
```

The equivalent js code would be:

```js
this.remotePlayerController = new cast.framework.RemotePlayerController(new cast.framework.RemotePlayer())
remotePlayerController.addEventListener(cast.framework.RemotePlayerEventType.IS_CONNECTED_CHANGED) {
    function() {
         console.log(\"Remote Player event: IS_CONNECTED_CHANGED\");
         return switchPlayers();
    }
}
```

Here's my receiver code, which exactly corresponds to step 7 of the [Cast Receiver codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-receiver/#7) and works correctly against the codelab's [sample sender](https://cast-tse-demo.firebaseapp.com/sender/):

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cast CAF Receiver</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/mediaplayer/1.0.0/media_player.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/shaka-player/2.5.5/shaka-player.compiled.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <cast-media-player></cast-media-player>
    <script src="//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/caf_receiver/v3/cast_receiver_framework.js"></script>
    <script>
        const context = cast.framework.CastReceiverContext.getInstance();
        const playerManager = context.getPlayerManager(); // the PlayerManager handles playback and provides hooks to plug-in custom logic

        context.start(); // initialize sdk
    </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

### What's wrong

Based on console logs that I've added, I know the event listener being added. Then, I click the cast button on my sender page, and my receiver app shows up on my TV. At this point, typing `cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance().getCastState()` into the sender console returns `"CONNECTED"` and the current session (
`cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance().getCurrentSession()`) is not null. BUT, the `IS_CONNECTED_CHANGED` event listener is never triggered. Neither the sender nor the receiver ([Chrome Remote Debugger](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/debugging) console) print errors or logs about this.

I've tried listening for `ANY_CHANGE` as well as `IS_CONNECTED_CHANGED`, but neither listener gets called.

### My Question

What's an appropriate way to trigger setup of the remote player? Is there something wrong with how I'm listening for the `IS_CONNECTED_CHANGED` event? Or should I be listening for something else entirely?

Answer (score 2):

HTML page example with Cast button using Chromecast framework API.
Upload the html code to webserver and viewed as webpage because CAST API cannot be loaded properly from local file HTML.

[example code](https://gist.github.com/zamroni111/5485c0dfa12c9dc490ef90a2b40a9ab0)
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0tFL.png)

Comment: Hi Mochamad! Welcome to StackOverflow!
This code looks good, but your answer needs more explanation. What does the code do, and how does it solve the question? Also, if you copied the code from somewhere (a Google sample project for example), please say where!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, my problem was that the sender never connected to the receiver! It never detected a connection, because there never was one. As far as I can tell, listening for `IS_CONNECTED_CHANGED` is a perfectly appropriate way to detect a connection, if it would occur.

How I know this: The sender did cause my TV to load the receiver app, but afterwards on the sender, `cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance().getCurrentSession()` was null (where "session" refers to a connection to a receiver) and, more tellingly, `cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance.getCastState()` returned `"NOT_CONNECTED"`. As far as I can tell, there was either never a time when the cast state was connected, or the connected state lasted for less than a second, even while the receiver kept going.